# Retrieve/Show columns based on user input

Tags: t-sql, select, ssms

I have two tables.

**MainTable**

[image: MainTable]

**FIELDS_ACTIVATION**

[image: Fields]

I will be building a page in ASP.NET from which a user will be able to view all records from MainSampleTable.

However, (due to GDPR) I have to build a stored procedure that enables the user to select a category from this page (possibly from a dropdown list). When the user selects Category 1, I will need the IsActive column fields for which the Category Id matches what the user selected, to become 1. So If user selects 1, Where Category Id = 1, Then IsActive shall =  1 (true) (Field activation table).

When that happens, I need to select/show the columns from the main sample table, that match the names of the field names in the field activation table that have a value of 1 in IsActive.

This is my code so far.

```
DECLARE @category INT = 1

                --Set Default Values (All disabled (false) until user selects a category)
                UPDATE Company.FileExtraction.FIELDS_ACTIVATION
                SET IsActive = 0

                --If Category is 1, Set IsActive to 1, Where CategoryId is 1 in FIELDS_ACTIVATION table
                IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CatOneTemp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #CatOneTemp
                IF @category = 1
                    BEGIN
                        UPDATE Company.FileExtraction.FIELDS_ACTIVATION
                        SET IsActive = 1
                        WHERE CategoryID = 1

                        --Select appropriate fields and put into temp table
                        SELECT REPLICATE('0', 10-LEN(EM.ColumnA)) + EM.ColumnA AS PolicyNumber,
                               REPLICATE('0', 7-LEN(ColumnB)) + ColumnB AS BOCBranch,
                               ColumnC + REPLICATE(' ', 10-LEN(ColumnC)) AS ContributionCode
                        INTO #CatOneTemp
                        FROM Company.FileExtraction.MainTable EM

                        SELECT * FROM #CatOneTemp
                    END
```

I cannot join the tables as I don't have common ground to do so. I've tried using a subquery but I can't get my head around how to form this sort of query.

I can't help but think there's a better approach to this, but this approach has been given to me by somebody else to implement, I can't go against this. Personally, I would have preferred that when the user selects one, select columnA and columnB, when 2, select columnC and columnD, without the IsActive column. But hey instructions are instructions. There's obviously a reason for this.

**EDIT**

I've updated the code. 
I would like the current code to do the `SELECT` *only if* the `IsActive` column in the Field Activation Table is 1 and only for the `FieldNames` that match the column names in the MainSampleTable.

Basically, I need the `IsActive = 1` to be a mandatory condition for the `SELECT` statements.

I've also checked here [Select records in on table based on conditions from another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163219/select-records-in-on-table-based-on-conditions-from-another-table) but this requires that the two tables have a common field. (Eg. type_id). The idea in that post is what I'm after.

Hope that makes sense, happy to make any clarifications if anything doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't pretty but it will at least get the answer that you want:

```
SELECT *
INTO #MainSampleTable
FROM (SELECT 'John' AS ColumnA, 'Doe' AS ColumnB, 'Clark St.' AS ColumnC, 'Telford' AS ColumnD, 'UK' AS ColumnE, '2300' AS ColumnF UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jane' AS ColumnA, 'Doe' AS ColumnB, 'Lister gdns.' AS ColumnC, 'London' AS ColumnD, 'UK' AS ColumnE, '2300' AS ColumnF UNION ALL
SELECT 'John' AS ColumnA, 'Smith' AS ColumnB, 'Clurk St.' AS ColumnC, 'Bradford' AS ColumnD, 'UK' AS ColumnE, '2300' AS ColumnF UNION ALL
SELECT 'John' AS ColumnA, 'Jones' AS ColumnB, 'Clork St.' AS ColumnC, 'Tellane' AS ColumnD, 'UK' AS ColumnE, '2325' AS ColumnF UNION ALL
SELECT 'John' AS ColumnA, 'Long' AS ColumnB, 'Clyrk St.' AS ColumnC, 'Ford' AS ColumnD, 'UK' AS ColumnE, '2350' AS ColumnF
) AS Names;


SELECT *
INTO #FieldActivationSample
FROM (SELECT '1' AS CategoryId, 'ColumnA' AS FieldName, 0 AS IsActive UNION ALL
SELECT '1' AS CategoryId, 'ColumnB' AS FieldName, 0 AS IsActive UNION ALL
SELECT '2' AS CategoryId, 'ColumnC' AS FieldName, 0 AS IsActive UNION ALL
SELECT '2' AS CategoryId, 'ColumnD' AS FieldName, 0 AS IsActive UNION ALL
SELECT '3' AS CategoryId, 'ColumnE' AS FieldName, 0 AS IsActive UNION ALL
SELECT '3' AS CategoryId, 'ColumnF' AS FieldName, 0 AS IsActive 
) AS Fields;



    --User input parameter
DECLARE @categoryId VARCHAR(1) = '1'

--If User selects 1 set IsActive to 1 Where Field Name = 'ColumnA' and 'ColumnB'
IF @categoryId = '1'
UPDATE #FieldActivationSample
SET IsActive = 1
WHERE FieldName IN ('ColumnA', 'ColumnB');


--This is where I am stuck

--Select the columns from MainSampleTable, 
--which have names that match values in the FieldName column,
--that have an IsActive status of 1, 
--from the FieldActivationTable
DECLARE @FieldList varchar(1000);
DECLARE @DynamicFields nvarchar(4000);
SELECT @FieldList = Stuff((Select ',' +replace(FieldName,'z','')
FROM (SELECT FieldName 
        FROM #FieldActivationSample
        WHERE IsActive = 1                      
      ) C1
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'');

SET @DynamicFields = 'SELECT ' + @FieldList + ' FROM #MainSampleTable';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicFields;


DROP TABLE #MainSampleTable;
DROP TABLE #FieldActivationSample;
```

Comment: The actual MainTable has hundreds of rows so adding each entry manually is undoable. The tables I have shown here are samples representing the general idea. Added the clarification in the post. Temp tables actually sound like a good idea though.

Comment: The temp tables are only so I can show my answer. You only need to use the part below your original "This is where I am stuck" comment.

Comment: Ok. How about the Drop Tables? I don’t want to drop any tables.

Comment: The way I delivered the answer, you should be able to load it into any server to test that my answer works. Drop table statements are also for the example, so you can drop the temporary tables after you are done testing.

Comment: Ok. I’ll be back to work in a week. I’ll give it a shot and get back to you then.

Comment: Hi. Back in office trying this solution. Tell me please what does this line do exactly? SELECT @FieldList = Stuff((Select ',' +replace(FieldName,'z','')

Comment: `SELECT @FieldList = Stuff((Select ',' +replace(FieldName,'z','')` Well, the replace function isn't needed but it would remove any z from the column names.. the rest of the line is the part that builds a comma separated list of FieldName and puts it into the @FieldList variable.

Comment: Changed the code up a bit. Tried the solution couldn’t get it to work. I’ve added the edit into the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simplified solution. What I think you need is the ability to use the FieldActivationSample table to stitch up columns for the query. To do this, you will need to create a dynamic query. The dynamic query column using Quotename and comes with a comma which you have to remove and then run.
Let me know if it works.

```
CREATE TABLE MainSampleTable (ColumnA varchar(20), ColumnB varchar(20),  ColumnC varchar(20), ColumnD varchar(20), ColumnE varchar(20),  ColumnF varchar(20))
INSERT INTO MainSampleTable
SELECT 'John', 'Doe', 'Clark St.', 'Telford', 'UK', '2300' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jane', 'Doe', 'Lister gdns.', 'London', 'UK', '2300' UNION ALL
SELECT 'John', 'Smith', 'Clurk St.', 'Bradford', 'UK', '2300' UNION ALL
SELECT 'John', 'Jones', 'Clork St.', 'Tellane', 'UK', '2325' UNION ALL
SELECT 'John', 'Long', 'Clyrk St.', 'Ford', 'UK', '2350'

CREATE TABLE FieldActivationSample (CategoryId INT, FieldName varchar(50), IsActive BIT)
INSERT INTO FieldActivationSample
SELECT '1', 'ColumnA', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT '1', 'ColumnB', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'ColumnC', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'ColumnD', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT '3', 'ColumnE', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT '3', 'ColumnF', 0 



--Ability to use a table to stitch columns using dynamic query --
DECLARE @ColumnList nvarchar(1000)=(SELECT Quotename(FieldName) + ',' FROM FieldActivationSample WHERE IsActive=1 FOR xml path(''))--- @Column List
SELECT @ColumnList = LEFT(@ColumnList, Len(@ColumnList) - 1)  --- Remove comma
--Generate Query ----
DECLARE @Dynamicsql nvarchar(1000)   = 'SELECT ' + @ColumnList + ' FROM MainSampleTable '
--Test Query  ---
PRINT (@Dynamicsql) 
--To run--
EXEC(@DynamicFields)
```

Comment: Ok. I’ll be back at the office in a week. I’ll post back then.

Comment: 1. Getting this: "Must declare the scalar variable "@DynamicFields"." and 2. The line you tell me to remove the comma from doesn't have a removable comma. What comma are you referring to?

Comment: hi NikosV, this section (line 24 declares and assigns "@DynamicFields" -DECLARE @Dynamicsql nvarchar(1000)   = 'SELECT ' ...

Comment: Also there is a comma added in the @ColumnList variable when you use the quotename function. The section with "--- Remove comma" removes it.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the solutions worked. I am trying something else and I've updated the code accordingly.