# How to select records from a table when a condition of another table is satisfied

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have this query that runs regularly.

```
SELECT REPLICATE('0', 10-LEN(PolicyNumber)) + PolicyNumber AS PolicyNumber,
       REPLICATE('0', 7-LEN(BOCBranch)) + BOCBranch AS BOCBranch,
       CIFNumber+ REPLICATE(' ', 8-LEN(CIFNumber)) AS CIFNumber,
       REPLICATE('0', 7-LEN(EmployeeNumber)) + EmployeeNumber AS EmployeeNumber,
       PremiumSign,
       REPLACE(REPLICATE('0',16-LEN(CAST(Premium AS VARCHAR))) + CAST(Premium AS VARCHAR),'.','') AS Premium, 
       CASE WHEN RegistrationDate IS NULL 
            THEN REPLICATE(' ', 8)
            ELSE REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),RegistrationDate,103),'/','')
       END AS RegistrationDate,
       ActivityCode + REPLICATE(' ', 10-LEN(ActivityCode)) AS ActivityCode,
       ActivityDescription + REPLICATE(' ', 255-LEN(ActivityDescription)) AS ActivityDescription,
       PolicyTypeCode + REPLICATE(' ', 10-LEN(PolicyTypeCode)) AS PolicyTypeCode,
       PolicyTypeDescription + REPLICATE(' ', 255-LEN(PolicyTypeDescription)) AS PolicyTypeDescription,
       ContributionCode + REPLICATE(' ', 10-LEN(ContributionCode)) AS ContributionCode,
       ContributionDescription + REPLICATE(' ', 255-LEN(ContributionDescription)) AS ContributionDescription,
       ActivityMilimetra + REPLICATE(' ', 1-LEN(ActivityMilimetra)) AS ActivityMilimetra,
       REPLICATE('0', 8-LEN(SourceCode)) + CAST(SourceCode AS varCHAR) AS SourceCode
FROM FileExtraction.EXTR_MILIMETRA
ORDER BY PolicyNumber
```

I have created a new table called FIELD_ACTIVATIONS as per managerial instructions like so:

```
FieldName                                          CategoryID  IsActive
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- --------
PolicyNumber                                       1           1
BOCBranch                                          1           1
CIFNumber                                          1           1
EmployeeNumber                                     1           0
PremiumSign                                        1           0
RegistrationDate                                   1           0
ActivityCode                                       1           0
ActivityDescription                                1           0
PolicyTypeCode                                     1           0
PolicyTypeDescription                              1           0
ContributionCode                                   1           0
ContributionDescription                            1           0
ActivityMilimetra                                  1           0
SourceCode                                         1           0
Premium                                            1           0
PolicyNumber                                       2           0
BOCBranch                                          2           0
CIFNumber                                          2           0
EmployeeNumber                                     2           1
PremiumSign                                        2           1
RegistrationDate                                   2           1
ActivityCode                                       2           0
ActivityDescription                                2           0
PolicyTypeCode                                     2           0
PolicyTypeDescription                              2           0
ContributionCode                                   2           0
ContributionDescription                            2           0
ActivityMilimetra                                  2           0
SourceCode                                         2           0
Premium                                            2           0
PolicyNumber                                       3           0
BOCBranch                                          3           0
CIFNumber                                          3           0
EmployeeNumber                                     3           0
PremiumSign                                        3           0
RegistrationDate                                   3           0
ActivityCode                                       3           1
ActivityDescription                                3           1
PolicyTypeCode                                     3           1
PolicyTypeDescription                              3           0
ContributionCode                                   3           0
ContributionDescription                            3           0
ActivityMilimetra                                  3           0
SourceCode                                         3           0
Premium                                            3           0
PolicyNumber                                       4           0
BOCBranch                                          4           0
CIFNumber                                          4           0
EmployeeNumber                                     4           0
PremiumSign                                        4           0
RegistrationDate                                   4           0
ActivityCode                                       4           0
ActivityDescription                                4           0
PolicyTypeCode                                     4           0
PolicyTypeDescription                              4           1
ContributionCode                                   4           1
ContributionDescription                            4           1
ActivityMilimetra                                  4           1
SourceCode                                         4           1
Premium                                            4           1
```

As you may notice, each column in the `SELECT` statement, is a FieldName in the table.

*What I need to do is to run that `SELECT` statement only for the columns that appear in FieldName that have a status of IsActive = 1. For the columns in the `SELECT` query that have a status of IsActive = 0, I would still like to select the column, but display it as an empty column.*

This is all without permanently deleting or altering anything from any tables.

I've tried using Cases, Subqueries, IFs and I cannot seem to come up with a solution that will not require future alteration if any details in the FIELD_ACTIVATIONS table change.

I've also looked at this link [Select records in on table based on conditions from another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163219/select-records-in-on-table-based-on-conditions-from-another-table) but this link presumes that there is a common field in both tables.

The main table named as "EXTR_MILIMETRA" displayed in the `SELECT` query has nothing in common with FIELD_ACTIVATION apart from the column name and the field name.

Here is a sample of the columns in "EXTR_MILIMETRA". (Not all columns are being shown because of limited screen space.) Each column show below is a FieldName is the table above.

[image: ColumnNames]

By asking this I'm risking being blocked due to consecutive previous downvotes. If any extra information is needed please let me know first instead of downvoting. If that's ok. I've really tried to describe my problem well enough.

Happy to make any clarifications.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You're going to need dynamic SQL to do this, I think.  But...there might be a better way of doing it without dynamic SQL.

Comment: I've never used dynamic SQL. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you would write that depends on if you need performance or not. If you don't have too many rows then you can do it like:

```
WITH active AS
(
   SELECT FieldName 
   FROM Field_Activations 
   WHERE CategoryId=1 AND IsActive=1
)
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM active WHERE FieldName='PolicyNumber')
    THEN REPLICATE('0', 10-LEN(PolicyNumber)) + PolicyNumber 
    ELSE '' END AS PolicyNumber,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM active WHERE FieldName='BOCBranch')
    then REPLICATE('0', 7-LEN(BOCBranch)) + BOCBranch
    ELSE '' end AS BOCBranch,
    --...
    FROM FileExtraction.EXTR_MILIMETRA
    ORDER BY PolicyNumber;
```

If you need some performance then you can write the above query as a dynamic query with a series of if and execute:

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(4000);  
declare @active table (FieldName varchar(100));

insert into @active (FieldName)
   SELECT FieldName 
   FROM Field_Activations 
   WHERE CategoryId=1 AND IsActive=1;


SET @SQLString = N'
SELECT ' +
        CASE when EXISTS 
          (SELECT * FROM @active WHERE FieldName = 'PolicyNumber')
        THEN 'REPLICATE(''0'', 10-LEN(PolicyNumber)) + PolicyNumber'
        ELSE '''''' END + ' AS PolicyNumber,' +
        CASE WHEN EXISTS 
          (SELECT * FROM @active WHERE FieldName = 'BOCBranch')
        THEN 'REPLICATE(''0'', 7-LEN(BOCBranch)) + BOCBranch'
        ELSE '''''' end + ' AS BOCBranch,' +
        --... +
        ' FROM FileExtraction.EXTR_MILIMETRA
          ORDER BY PolicyNumber;'
print @SQLString
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString;
```

Comment: Looks good and neat. I presume FieldStates is my Field Activations table? Yes you’re right about the dupes in Field Activations. Thats intentional. Example. PolicyNumber is only Active for CategoryId 1 and Inactive for other categories.

Comment: @NikosV, yes I named it like that for sampling :) Don't forget I didn't include a CategoryId criteria.

Comment: Ok. Say later on PolicyNumber stops being active. I’ll have to alter the code won’t I?

Comment: @NikosV, No code stays put. Only the values in 'fieldStates' change.

Comment: Ok nice. I’ll be back in the office tomorrow and I’ll try it. I’ll post back.

Comment: Sorry one clarification. The record that will ultimately be selected is PolicyNumber from the EXTR_MILIMETRA table. FieldStates just has the name of the column and it’s active status. I want to select PolicyNumber with Replicate like you added with its data from EXTR_MILIMETRA if PolicyNumber field has a value of 1 in IsActive. Is there any chance the code can be altered for this?

Comment: @NikosV, it is doing just like you are saying. Data is selected from EXTR_MILIMETRA, but only checked if would be selected or empty from the other FIELD)ACTIVATIONS table. Sorry I didn't notice initially that it had a name and said it to be fieldStates. I will soon polish the code a bit to make it more readable and effective (with also CategoryId).

Comment: @NikosV, OK edited. I hardcoded CategoryId as 1 but you can make it a parameter if you like.

Comment: Hi. Getting an Invalid object name 'active' error. I'm using the second example. Any ideas?

Comment: Settled for first choice for 1. Easier readability. 2. Colleagues haven't really used dynamic sql I don't want to confuse them if they ever see it. 3. Looks like a simpler approach. Now if there's a performance issue later on, we'll see how we handle it then. Thanks.

Comment: @NikosV, are you still getting "active" error? It is the CTE's name.

Comment: I used the other solution it’s perfectly fine.

Comment: @NikosV, that is OK but I see why it is giving error in second, I would correct that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

@NikosV you need is a dynamic query. I have called it @DynamicQuery and a method to assign those columns that you are intersted in hiding will have NULL added to them, rendering their output to be blanks. Have a look at this mock up, just change the TABLENAME to the actual name of the table you want to pull the data from and use the actual FIELD_ACTIVATIONS table you said you creatd.

```
DECLARE @FIELD_ACTIVATIONS TABLE (FieldName  varchar(200), CategoryID  int, IsActive bit)

INSERT INTO @FIELD_ACTIVATIONS

SELECT 'PolicyNumber',  1,  1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'BOCBranch', 1,  1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'CIFNumber', 1,  1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'EmployeeNumber',    1,  0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PremiumSign',   1,  0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'RegistrationDate',  1,  0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'ActivityCode',  1,  0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'ActivityDescription',   1,  0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PolicyTypeCode',    1,  0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PolicyTypeDescription', 1,  0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'ContributionCode',  1,  0



DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += FieldName+','
    FROM (SELECT p.FieldName+''+CASE WHEN IsActive=0 THEN '=NULL' ELSE '' END FieldName
    FROM @FIELD_ACTIVATIONS p 

    ) AS x;




DECLARE @Querycolumns VARCHAR(MAX)=(select  left (@columns, Len ( @columns) - 1 ))

DECLARE @Dynamicquery NVARCHAR(MAX) = '

      SELECT '+ @Querycolumns +'
      FROM 
      TABLENAME   
      '
```

The output query will be run like this :

```
SELECT PolicyNumber,BOCBranch,CIFNumber,EmployeeNumber=NULL,PremiumSign=NULL,RegistrationDate=NULL,ActivityCode=NULL,ActivityDescription=NULL,PolicyTypeCode=NULL,PolicyTypeDescription=NULL,ContributionCode=NULL
      FROM 
      TABLENAME
```