# Counting number of user skills per user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables **users**, **skills** and **user_skills**

**users** table with columns:

```
id,name,sex
```

**skills** table with columns:

```
id,name,view_count
```

and **user_skills** table with columns:

```
id,user_id,skill_id
```

I want to output total count of skills based on user selection which are store on **user_skill** expected output table is:

| Skill name | user_skill_count |
| --- | --- |
| Programming | 8 |
| Database | 12 |
| Accounts | 9 |
| Analysis | 12 |

I have tried this SQL query

```
select `skills`.*, (select count(*) from `user_skills`
                    where `skills`.`id` = `user_skills`.`skill_id`) as `user_skill_count`
from `skills`
```

but it returns other skills which user has not selected and output count 0 as table below

| Skill name | user_skill_count |
| --- | --- |
| Programming | 8 |
| Database | 0 |
| Accounts | 9 |
| Analysis | 0 |

I want the results to be only the skill users has selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple join in your query:

```sql
SELECT `skills`.`name`, count(*) as `user_skill_count`
FROM `skills`
INNER JOIN `user_skills` ON `skills`.`id` = `user_skills`.`skill_id`
GROUP BY `skills`.`id`, `skills`.`name`
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to select records in one table based on the conditions in another one. Maybe this thread will help you?

[Select records in on table based on conditions from another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163219/select-records-in-on-table-based-on-conditions-from-another-table/19163275)